# Setting the value of a angular mat-select

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I cannot seem to set the selected value of a mat-select dropdown.  I have a component for adding services and use the same component to display services that have already been added. I have attempted using NgModel and specifying the service.serviceId as the value but it never seems to appear in the dropdown as selected. How can I use this component to allow the user to select services and also manually set the displayed service using the data from `bookingServiceTime` as the preset selected value.  Appreciate any help. Thanks.

```
     <mat-form-field>
          <mat-select placeholder="Select a service" [(ngModel)]="selectedService" required (change)="changeService($event.value)">
            <mat-optgroup *ngFor="let serviceGroup of serviceGroups" [label]="serviceGroup.serviceGroupName">
              <mat-option *ngFor="let service of serviceGroup?.services" [value]="service">
                {{service?.serviceName}}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-optgroup>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>

  ngOnInit() {
this.serviceGroupService.serviceGroups.subscribe(sg => {});

this.selectedService.serviceId = this.bookingservicetime.serviceTime.service.serviceId;
this.selectedServiceTime = this.bookingservicetime.serviceTime;
}
```

service.ts

```
export class Service extends Base {
serviceId: number;
serviceName: string;
serviceDescription: string;
serviceGroupId: number;
tax: boolean;
commission: boolean;
onlineBooking: boolean;
serviceTimes: ServiceTime[];
blockedTimeBefore?: number;
blockedTimeAfter?: number;
staff: any[]; // Need to change to StaffService.
disabled: boolean;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to bind

```
   <mat-option *ngFor="let service of serviceGroup?.services" [value]="service.serviceName">
                {{service?.serviceName}}
   </mat-option>
```

Comment: This did not work, the selected value is still not set unfortunately.

Comment: can you post what you have in serviceGroup?.services

Comment: added the services model

Comment: i was asking for the JSON data

Comment: blockedTimeAfter
:
null
blockedTimeBefore
:
null
commission
:
false
createdOn
:
"2018-06-16T19:16:59.8089437Z"
createdUserId
:
1
disabled
:
false
onlineBooking
:
false
serviceDescription
:
null
serviceGroupId
:
1
serviceId
:
2002
serviceName
:
"Haircut"
serviceTimes
:
(2) [{…}, {…}]
staff
:
null
tax
:
false
updatedOn
:
"2018-06-16T19:20:32.2204202Z"
updatedUserId
:
1

Comment: can you add JSON.stringify(this.serviceGroup.services)) and post here